# Растровая развертка круга

Tags: c#, алгоритм, графика

Как выглядит алгоритм растровой развертки КРУГА по алгоритму Брезенхема? На просторах интернета могу найти только алгоритм развертки окружности :(

--

Как сместить цент?

```
public void Draw(int R, int _x, int _y)
    {
        int y = _y;
        int x = R;
        int d = 3 - 2 * R;
        while (x > -y)
        {
            int tempx = _x, tempy = _y;
            int i = 0;
            while (i < x)
            {
                PutPixel(GetX(x - tempx), GetY(y));
                PutPixel(GetX(-x + tempx), GetY(y));
                i++;
                tempx++;
            }
            i = 0;
            tempx = _x;

            while (i < x)
            {
                PutPixel(GetX(x - tempx), GetY(-y));
                PutPixel(GetX(-x + tempx), GetY(-y));
                i++;
                tempx++;
            }
            if (d < 0)
                d = d - 4 * y + 6;
            else
            {
                tempy = _y;
                i = 0;
                while (i < -y)
                {
                    PutPixel(GetX(y - tempy), GetY(x));
                    PutPixel(GetX(-y + tempy), GetY(x));
                    i++;
                    tempy--;
                }
                i = 0;
                tempy = _y;
                while (i < -y)
                {
                    PutPixel(GetX(y - tempy), GetY(-x));
                    PutPixel(GetX(-y + tempy), GetY(-x));
                    i++;
                    tempy--;
                }
                d = d - 4 * (y + x) + 10;
                x--;
            }
            Form1.Wait(0.03);
            y--;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Уточните, что вам мешает залить внутренности окружности и получить круг?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%B0 читали?

Comment: @SeeSharp, читал, но там к сожалению только развертка ОКРУЖНОСТИ, а мне нужен КРУГ

Comment: Проверять координаты и если они внутри круга залить?

Comment: @Kromster, ну вообще существует алгоритм как залить внутренность окружности, его я и ищу

Comment: @SeeSharp, есть алгоритм Брезенхема, который рассказывает как это делать...

Comment: @Данил, алгоритм для круга такой же, как и для окружности. Разница только в том, как закрашиваются пиксели. Для окружности на каждой итерации закрашиваются только вычисленные точки, а для круга - проводятся линии между этими точками (между парами точек, находящимися на одном уровне по какой-либо из осей). Этими линиями и закрашивается вся внутренняя область.

Comment: @t3f, спасибо, именно это я и скал) А не подскажите, как можно сместить цент окружности при рисовании, а то у меня всякая бяка получается, когда пытаюсь сместить центр

Comment: @AK Код в студии)

Comment: Если `_x` и `_y` - это координаты центра, то фигурировать они у вас должны только в `PutPixel` в качестве смещений и больше нигде. Каким образом и зачем они у вас фигурируют где-то еще - мне не ясно.

Comment: @AnT, ну так они и используется так

Comment: @Данил: Это как это "так"? У вас значение `_y` сразу же копируется в `y` и далее через `y` влияет на решения, принимаемые алгоритмом Брезенхема. Это очевидная чушь. Алгоритм Брезенхема инвариантен к положению центра окружности. А у вас он очевидным образом зависит от `_y`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Классический алгоритм Брезенхема генерирует точки для четвертинки окружности. Остальные точки получаются отражением сгенерированной точки относительно осей координат. Таким образом вы на каждом шаге алгоритма получаете четыре точки - начала и концы двух горизонтальных диапазонов пикселов, которые нужно закрасить. Вот и получился алгоритм растеризации круга.

```
void draw_pixels(int x1, int x2, int y)
{
  line(x1, y, x2, y);
}

void BresenhamCircle(int cx, int cy, int radius)
{
  int x = radius, y = 0;
  int D = 2 * (1 - radius);

  while (x >= 0)
  {
    draw_pixels(cx - x, cx + x, cy + y);
    draw_pixels(cx - x, cx + x, cy - y);

    if (D < 0 && 2 * D + 2 * x - 1 <= 0)
    { 
      ++y;
      D += 2 * y + 1;
    }
    else if (D > 0 && 2 * D - 2 * y - 1 >= 0)
    {
      --x;
      D -= 2 * x - 1;
    }
    else
    {
      --x, ++y;
      D += 2 * y - 2 * x + 2;
    }
  }
}
```

Вариант Мичнера генерирует точки для одной осьмушки окружности, а остальные точки получаются отражением относительно осей координат и диагоналей. На каждом шаге вы получаете восемь точек - начала и концы четырех горизонтальных диапазонов пикселов, которые нужно закрасить. Снова 
получился алгоритм растеризации круга.

```
void MichenerCircle(int cx, int cy, int radius)
{
  int x = radius, y = 0;
  int d = 3 - 2 * radius;

  while (y <= x)
  {
    draw_pixels(cx - x, cx + x, cy - y);
    draw_pixels(cx - x, cx + x, cy + y);
    draw_pixels(cx - y, cx + y, cy + x);
    draw_pixels(cx - y, cx + y, cy - x);

    if (d <= 0)
    { 
      d += 4 * y + 6;
      ++y;
    }
    else
    { 
      d += 4 * (y - x) + 10;
      --x, ++y;
    }
  }
}
```

Выбирайте, что вам больше нравится.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]